# Careers Site Fruitful for Senior Architects/Managers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I'm considering posting my resume on the careers site.  I have about 15 years of industry experience.  I'm wondering if anyone who is very senior in the industry has had success on the careers site.

Is there a list of success stories anywhere?  Does anyone care to share their experience (positive or negative)?

Answer (score 1):

To answer one of your questions, [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/careers-success-stories/) are a few success stories